# check if keys exist in object and if it has value

Tags: javascript, typescript

How do we check the keys and compare it to the data object , if one or more keys from the keys array does not exist in object data or if it exist or key exists and the key value has no value or null or undefined then return false else return true.

For example keys has a key summary and it exists on object data but the value is empty so it should return false;

I've tried  Object.keys and used includes but cant seem to work it out, maybe someone has an idea. Thanks.

#currentCode

```
 const sample =  Object.entries(sampleOject).some((value) => {
          return keys.includes(value[0]) ? false : (value[1] === null || value[1] === "");
      })
```

Thanks.

#keys

```
const keys =  [
    'summary',
    'targetRecdate',
    'majorPositiveAttributes',
    'generalRealEstateConcernsorChallenges',
    'terminationPayment',
    'effectiveDate',
    'brokerCommission',
    'brokerRebate',
    'netEffectiveBrokerCommission']
```

#sample object data

```
{
    "dealDispositionType": "A",
    "majorPositiveAttributes": "a",
    "terminationPayment": "31",
    "netEffectiveBrokerCommission": -12189,
    "brokerCommission": "123",
    "brokerRebate": "12312",
    "isPharmacyRestriction": 0,
    "periodOfRestriction": null,
    "pharmacyRestrictionDate": null,
    "targetRecdate": "2022-10-20",
    "isLandLordConsent": false,
    "summary: ""
}
```

Comment: What is your expected output??

Comment: a boolean......

Comment: A single boolean? True if all those keys exist with a value?

Comment: According to mdn, 

const car = { make: 'Honda', model: 'Accord', year: 1998 };
console.log('make' in car);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `every()` with `hasOwnProperty` and additional checks for empty strings etc

```js
const result = keys.every(key => {
    return data.hasOwnProperty(key) && data[key] !== ''
}, {});
```

```js
const keys =  [
    'summary',
    'targetRecdate',
    'majorPositiveAttributes',
    'generalRealEstateConcernsorChallenges',
    'terminationPayment',
    'effectiveDate',
    'brokerCommission',
    'brokerRebate',
    'netEffectiveBrokerCommission'
];

const data = {
    "dealDispositionType": "A",
    "majorPositiveAttributes": "a",
    "terminationPayment": "31",
    "netEffectiveBrokerCommission": -12189,
    "brokerCommission": "123",
    "brokerRebate": "12312",
    "isPharmacyRestriction": 0,
    "periodOfRestriction": null,
    "pharmacyRestrictionDate": null,
    "targetRecdate": "2022-10-20",
    "isLandLordConsent": false,
    "summary": ""
};

const result = keys.every(key => {
    return data.hasOwnProperty(key) && data[key] !== ''
}, {});

console.log(result); // False
```

Comment: The ouput should only one bolean either true or false Sir

Comment: Please see my edit m8

Answer (score 1):

I just optimized your code.

```
const sample =  Object.entries(sampleOject).map(([key, value]) => {
   return keys.includes(key) ? value ? true : false : false;
})
```

...

```js
const keys =  [
'summary',
'targetRecdate',
'majorPositiveAttributes',
'generalRealEstateConcernsorChallenges',
'terminationPayment',
'effectiveDate',
'brokerCommission',
'brokerRebate',
'netEffectiveBrokerCommission']

const obj = {
    "dealDispositionType": "A",
    "majorPositiveAttributes": "a",
    "terminationPayment": "31",
    "netEffectiveBrokerCommission": -12189,
    "brokerCommission": "123",
    "brokerRebate": "12312",
    "isPharmacyRestriction": 0,
    "periodOfRestriction": null,
    "pharmacyRestrictionDate": null,
    "targetRecdate": "2022-10-20",
    "isLandLordConsent": false,
    "summary": "test"
}

let arr = [];

const result = Object.entries(obj).map(([key, val]) => {
    if (keys.includes(key)) {
        if ((val !== '') && (val !== 'undefined') && (val !== 'null') ) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
})

const getValue = result.includes(true);

console.log(getValue)
```

Comment: It should only return 1 boolean Sir not an array of booleans.  if one or more keys from the keys array does not exist in object data or if it exist or key exists and the key value has no value or null or undefined then return false else return true.

Comment: You have a bug with `if (val)`. It will be **false positive** while checking `isPharmacyRestriction` because `0` would be identified as *falsy* value

Comment: If one value is true then return true otherwise return false , currently you are return an array

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be to check whether all `keys` are present in `data` with the help of `.every`.
Also non-strict `!=` will check if certain **key** contain neither `null` nor `undefined`

```js
const keys =  [
    'summary',
    'targetRecdate',
    'majorPositiveAttributes',
    'generalRealEstateConcernsorChallenges',
    'terminationPayment',
    'effectiveDate',
    'brokerCommission',
    'brokerRebate',
    'netEffectiveBrokerCommission'];
const data = {
    "dealDispositionType": "A",
    "majorPositiveAttributes": "a",
    "terminationPayment": "31",
    "netEffectiveBrokerCommission": -12189,
    "brokerCommission": "123",
    "brokerRebate": "12312",
    "isPharmacyRestriction": 0,
    "periodOfRestriction": null,
    "pharmacyRestrictionDate": null,
    "targetRecdate": "2022-10-20",
    "isLandLordConsent": false,
    "summary": ""
};

const check = (obj, keys) => keys.every((key) =>  
    key in obj && obj[key] != undefined);

console.log(check(data, keys));
```

Answer (score 0):

According to mdn,

```
const car = { make: 'Honda', model: 'Accord', year: 1998 };
console.log('make' in car); // output: true
```